# GooglePlayGames 0.9.64 x Unity 2018.4.2f1 AppCrash

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I got crash in GooglePlayGames 0.9.64 
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

[NativeBridgeActivity.java](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/source/SupportLib/PlayGamesPluginSupport/src/main/java/com/google/games/bridge/NativeBridgeActivity.java)

error log :

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
    Unity version     : 2018.4.2f1
    Device model      : OPPO CPH1853
    Device fingerprint: OPPO/CPH1853/CPH1853:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.026/1559663459:user/release-keys

    Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
          at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult (Instrumentation.java:1944)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1618)
          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4668)
          at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4599)
          at com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity.startActivityForResult (NativeBridgeActivity.java:86)
          at com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity.onStart (NativeBridgeActivity.java:62)
          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1335)
          at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:7245)
          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2912)
```

I check this code find this , maybe wrong in here , but I have no idea. What happened?

```
Intent bridgedIntent = (Intent) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(BRIDGED_INTENT);
```

Comment: make sure you have your activity added to manifest

Comment: This case I dont know what activity should open , How to know that ? @SathyaBaman

Comment: I think this is an activity to show achievements or leaderboard